# Can't turn On PHP display_errors

Tags: php, adsapi-php.ini

I am working on Ubuntu 18.04 and for my projects I want PHP to display errors. As `sudo`, I did:

```
display_errors = On
error_reporting = E_ALL
```

Then restart Apache2 service but I still don't get any errors reporting.

I both modified `php.ini` in `apache2` and `cli` folder and in the 2 versions of PHP (php7.0 and php7.2) on my system.

On `phpinfo()` I always get:

```
display_errors = Off
```

Comment: `display_startup_errors` ? also do `php -i |grep .ini` and see what php.ini file is actually being loaded

Comment: your `phpinfo()` should tell you which php.ini file is being used

Comment: Configuration File (php.ini) Path => /etc/php/7.2/cli
Loaded Configuration File => /etc/php/7.2/cli/php.ini


phpinfo() tells me dispay_startup_errors = On and i still have display_errors = Off whereas modified the correct php.ini

Comment: so you just need to edit the `/etc/php/7.2/cli/php.ini ` file -> search for display_errors and see how many entries are there, you may have added yours before another one is declared that sets it to off

Comment: That's what i explained in my first post... everything is ok in /etc/php/7.2/cli/php.ini

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did found a solution

I added this line **php_flag  display_errors On** to my **.htaccess** file. Errors are now displayed.

Answer (score 2):

I had same problem with php 7.1 on my Ubuntu 18.04 (have several versions of php too).

The problem can be is that you need to **restart** the **php-fpm** instead **apache2**.

In my case, I found that a **php7.1-fpm** have been installed and activated.

Run **phpinfo();** and look at the **"Server API"** row.

If it's something like "FPM" then you need to configure only:

```
 /etc/php/[current_php_ver]/fpm/php.ini file.
```

Or look at the **"Configuration File (php.ini) Path"** row for your php.ini path.

And then run:

```
sudo service php[current_php_ver]-fpm restart
```

**P.S:**
Change [current_php_ver] on your current php version, for example:

```
sudo service php7.1-fpm restart
```

Answer (score 1):

Try editing your php.ini.temp file, if you have one, and restarting your host server.

Answer (score 0):

MAMP/bin/php/*current-version*/conf/php.ini

Comment: Please provide more detailed information and additional explanation.